# tflite-model-maker and tflite-support fail to install using pip

Tags: python, pip, tflite

I have been trying to set up tflite-model-maker using pip for the past day and the install seems to run indefinitely. I am aware of the previously asked questions and the solution involving requirements.txt, however that solution has failed as well because pip can't seem to find tflite-support versions 0.4.2 and above for my machine (installed only version 0.1.0a1) and I can't find any clear instructions on how to install bazel to compile my own .whl file for tflite-support. I am running a 64-bit windows 10.

I am looking for any helpful advice on how to solve this as I am running a bit behind on my project.